# why save value come "null" (trying to save image in encode64)?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to save image in encoded64 and than get the value of image from local storage .But I am getting null value why ?

here is my fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/sAH8w/7/

```
function getBase64Image(img) {
    // Create an empty canvas element
    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas.width = img.width;
    canvas.height = img.height;

    // Copy the image contents to the canvas
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

    // Get the data-URL formatted image
    // Firefox supports PNG and JPEG. You could check img.src to
    // guess the original format, but be aware the using "image/jpg"
    // will re-encode the image.
    var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    try {
    localStorage.setItem("elephant", dataURL);
}
catch (e) {
    alert('error')
    console.log("Storage failed: " + e);
}

    //return dataURL.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, "");
}
```

Comment: Fiddle added to my answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This minor change fix the issue:

```
 $('#save').click(function(){
    var image = new Image();
    image.src = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/t2ywui846zp58ye/plus_minus_icons.png?m=";
    getBase64Image(image);

 })
```

#### Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/robertrozas/sAH8w/15/

#### Update(get button): http://jsfiddle.net/robertrozas/sAH8w/17/

Comment: can you please change the fiddle ?

Comment: I'm testing this on Chrome...this is the error the user was getting: `Failed to execute 'drawImage' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': No function was found that matched the signature provided. `

Comment: I want to check on chrome and firefox

Comment: @RobertRozas I am getting data when i click get button

Comment: what does it mean ..If I need to use save valuee how I will use

Comment: You are getting garbage from your localstorage...go to Resources->LocalStorage->fiddle.shell.net and delete the elephant ...now refresh the fiddle

Comment: thanks a good answer .you are adding one more save image on click of save button ..I don't need that can we add that image on get button click

Comment: This is the line that draw the image: `ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);` ...originally that was not working either...i'm glad to help...cheers

Comment: But how I will used save value of image..actually I don't know how to use save value..my Question is this last help